# Polymer wysiwyg and Jquery! How to?

Tags: jquery, editor, wysiwyg, polymer-1.0

I want to integrate a wysiwyg editor into my dom-module, but i have not had success until now. The problem is the shadow dom and the jquery plugin. Do you know some tutorials or guides I can reading about this problem ? thank a lot. ﻿

Comment: What wysiwyg editor are you trying to use?  What jQuery plugin?  Can you post examples of what you have tried so far?